# import XML file via AJAX

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

The code below does most of what I need. The function is run every time a new image is loaded onto the page. However this has created 100 server requests to the same xml file.. which is not good lets be honest.
So how do I rearange this function so only 1 xml request is used (even though im pulling 1 element out where i = id, the whole xml file is still cached) so i know i can use it.

```
function loadImages(i){ 
i++;
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sites.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: "true",
        success: function(xml) 
        {
// these are the id's of images i do not want to load  
            var a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19,18,60,61,50,49,79,78,81,82,80,70,90,91,92,93,94];

            if ( a.indexOf( 2 ) !== -1 ) { // do this if not an 1 of the id's above
            var img = $(xml).find('image[id=' + i + ']'),
            id = img.attr('id'),
            url = img.find('url').text();

            $('#loading'+i).html('<img src="'+url+'" onLoad="loadImages('+i+')" />').hide();
            $('#loading'+i).fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`AjaxQ`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/) plugin.

> - Browsers impose a limit on the number of open connections to the
>   server. All requests that do not fit
>   in the limit are going to wait for
>   being run anyway. Internet Explorer
>   does not open more than 2 connections
>   per server at a time by default.
>   Mozilla Firefox, Opera and Safari have
>   a limit of 8 connections per server.
> - Sometimes it is essential to avoid flooding the server with plenty
>   of simultaneous AJAX requests.
> - Web application needs AJAX requests to run one by one by design,
>   the order is important.

Comment: Just had a browse at that, and it looks like it is used for more than one xml file. My problem is I only have 1 xml file and its getting read 100 times. 
See this screenshot: http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7321/96968992.jpg

Comment: @Adam: It has nothing to do with xml file, it allows you to delay and/or limit your ajax requests.